# Reference masterpage variables from control in child page?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, webforms, master-pages, web-user-controls

Is it possible to access Masterpage variables from a web user control that is in a child page? I know you can access them in child pages by adding the following

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Master.master" %>
```

It doesn't seem to work when trying to access from a Web control that is inside a child page

Comment: Sounds brittle. What have you tried? Member variables? Public properties?

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea.  How do you know your user control will be used on a page which has the correct master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User Controls essentially should be unaware of any pages outside the control.  The better approach would be to have the control expose properties and events that the page itself (master page or normal) will use to set and retrieve values. Take this simple example:

```
    class PassValueEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public event EventHandler<PassValueEventArgs> RequestingValue;

    public void ControlDoingWork()
    {
        PassValueEventArgs e = new PassValueEventArgs();
        if (RequestingValue != null)
        {
            RequestingValue(this, e);
        }
        string fromHandlingPage = "Received " + e.Value + " from a handling page.";
    }
```

Then whenever the user control should have a value, the page containing the user control can just handle the RequestingValue event and send the value to the user control. Otherwise just expose a public property of the user control, which you can even make databound, for an even easier solution.

Adding a complete example of the event-driven approach:

WebUserControl1EventArgs.cs

```
public class WebUserControl1EventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public double ValueToSquare { get; set; }
}
```

WebUserControl1.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplicationCS1_net20.WebUserControl1" %>

Text below will display "Nothing passed from parent page." if the event is unhandled,
else will display the square of the number passed if handled.<br /><br />
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Larger" Text="Nothing passed from parent page."></asp:Label>
```

WebUserControl1.ascx.cs

```
public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler<WebUserControl1EventArgs> RequestingNumber;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ControlDoingWork();
    }

    private void ControlDoingWork()
    {
        if (RequestingNumber != null)
        {
            WebUserControl1EventArgs e = new WebUserControl1EventArgs();
            RequestingNumber(this, e);
            Label1.Text = (e.ValueToSquare * e.ValueToSquare).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

WebForm1.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplicationCS1_net20.WebForm1" %>

<%@ Register src="WebUserControl1.ascx" tagname="WebUserControl1" tagprefix="uc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <uc1:WebUserControl1 ID="WebUserControl11" runat="server" 
            OnRequestingNumber="WebUserControl11_RequestingNumber" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

WebForm1.aspx.cs

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void WebUserControl11_RequestingNumber(object sender, WebUserControl1EventArgs e)
    {
        e.ValueToSquare = 3.3;
    }
}
```

WebForm2.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplicationCS1_net20.WebForm2" %>

<%@ Register src="WebUserControl1.ascx" tagname="WebUserControl1" tagprefix="uc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <uc1:WebUserControl1 ID="WebUserControl11" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

WebForm2.aspx.cs

```
public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: That's a pretty good idea. Could you provide a full example of the above (with a dummy page passing a value to the user control)? I don't get how the user passes the values from page to control using that technique

Answer (score 0):

Use the Page's Master property to access to it's masterpage. After that you can you FindControl method or use the master's public properties if it have any. For example in the master page code behind:

```
public Label Title { get { return lblTitle; } }
```

Comment: There has got to be a better way to communicate 'something' with a user-control. What if the control is used on a page that doesn't have this Master?

Comment: Then you can access directly to the control from the page by useing it's ID (as a variable) or by using the page's (or any other parent control) FindControl method. After that you can use any public property, method, field of the user control.